# Undefined when passing DOM object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am (attempting) to have a table which can switch the background color based on an RGB value, where each row of the table has clickable `<td>`s, and they will add up to give and RGB value (eg. first row is +/- 123, second row is +/- 123.

**#2**: The issue I'm running into currently is that when I attempt to pass my DOM  object from my listener-creating for loop to the `switch_JS' function, the DOM that is being passed in`domobj` is undefined.

I would then like to switch the value of the hidden inputs inside of the `<td>`s each time the user clicks, and define a separate function (probably not in the JS) to add them up and render a rgb color based on that.

As I said, **the real issue is above as #2**, but any other help would be greatly appreciated. I am very new to programming in general, and this is mainly for my own learning.

```
<script>

var JS_elements = document.getElementsByClassName("JS")

for (y = 0; y < JS_elements.length; y++){
x = JS_elements[y].getElementsByTagName("input")[0]
alert(String(x.value)) **this loop runs 3 times, and puts 'false' to the alert pop-up each time

JS_elements[y].addEventListener('click', function() {
    switch_JS(JS_elements[y].getElementsByTagName("input")[0]);
});

function testfunc() {
    alert("TestFunc");
}

function true_switch(val) {
    document.getElementById("testblock").innerHTML += "true_switch worked; "; <!-- debug line -->
    if (val == true) {
        return false;
    } else if (val == false) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Error #475989 in function true_switch");
    }
}

function switch_JS(domobj) {
    <!-- takes as input an HTML object, and switched the value from true to false, or from false to true -->
    document.getElementById("testblock").innerHTML = document.getElementById("testblock").innerHTML + "Step 1 worked; "; <!-- debug line -->
    alert(String(domobj)); <!-- debug line -->
    val = domobj.querySelector("input").value;
    document.getElementById("testblock").innerHTML += "Step 2 worked; "; <!-- debug line -->
    if ((typeof val) != Boolean) {
        alert("Error, non-boolean passed into switch_JS");
        document.getElementById("testblock").innerHTML += "1st if worked; ";
    } else {
        domobj.querySelector("input").value = true_switch(HTML.value);
        document.getElementById("testblock").innerHTML += "else worked; "; <!-- debug line -->
    }
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="testblock">Testblock: </div>
    <header>
        <hr>
            <p>- Header Background Color Controller -</p>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Javascript Controller:</td>
                    <td class="JS">Red
                        <input type="hidden" value='false'>
                    </td>
                    <td class="JS">Green
                        <input type="hidden" value='false'>
                    </td>
                    <td class="JS">Blue
                        <input type="hidden" value='false'>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>jQuery Controller:</td>
                    <td class="jQ" value=false>Red</td>
                    <td class="jQ" value=false>Green</td>
                    <td class="jQ" value=false>Blue</td>
                <tr>
            </table>
        <hr>
    </header>
    <div class="main_div">

</div>
```

Comment: A bit off topic, but you could replace  `if (val == true) {
        return false;
    } else if (val == false) {
        return true;
    }` with `return !val`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: Why are you using HTML comments inside a script block?

Comment: I'm not sure what the appropriate type of comment is to be honest. This JavaScript is in an HTML file, instead of a file.js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Closure - use `this` instead of the array element
2. use an onload function
3. domObj is a node list so this will not work either: `val = domobj.querySelector("input").value;`

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/famqm0v2/)

```
window.onload=function() {
  var JS_elements = document.getElementsByClassName("JS")

  // why not use document.querySelectorAll(".JS");

  for (y = 0; y < JS_elements.length; y++){
    JS_elements[y].addEventListener('click', function() {
        switch_JS(this); // do not use [y] here
    });
  }
}
```

and then this will work when you pass in (this)

```
val = domobj.querySelector("input").value;
```

Update for 2020

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".JS")].forEach(function() {
    this.addEventListener('click', function() {
        switch_JS(this); 
    });
  })
})
```

but I suggest you delegate to the nearest static container

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in example i printed 2 console one for your **input** and one for your **i**

**So your problem  is:**

> when in listener function you are trying to access
>   **JS_elements[y].childNodes** so at that time your **Y** is  **4** and your Class Js array length is **0-3** and because of **for loop** Y will
>   be incremented to 4 so you got **undefined** because  **JS_elements[4]** is
>   not present in your array.

**so use this.chiledNode in**

see this one type of solution :

**Working example**:http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/gqce9htx/

```
var input = document.querySelectorAll('input');
  console.log(input)
   for(var i=0;i<input.length;i++){
      input[i].addEventListener('input', function()
      {  
         console.log(input)
         console.log(i)
         console.log('input changed to: ', this.value);
      });

 }
```

Comment: my loop only runs 3 times, and it accurately catches the three elements that I'm looking for.

Comment: you are right but in for loop you are using y++ so at 3 time your y   will become 4